# How to access multiple sites on XAMPP over the Internet

Tags: apache, xampp, httpd.conf, vhosts, portforwarding

I need some advice how to change the XAMPP configuration so that I can access more than one website over the Internet.

This is my current configuration. It works when I try to access both `site1` and `site2` locally but it only works for `site1` if I try to access it over the Internet:

**httpd.conf**:
`Listen 80`

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:\site1"
  ServerName site1.com
  <Directory "C:\site1">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:\site2"
  ServerName site2.com
  <Directory "C:\site2">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

I access `site1` over the internet like this:
`my-ip-address:80`

Now for the second website I tried doing this:

**httpd.conf**:

`Listen 80`

`Listen 8001`

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:8001>
      DocumentRoot "C:\site2"
      ServerName site2.com
      <Directory "C:\site2">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
      </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

and tried accessing the second website this way:

`my-ip-address:8001`

However, this does not work. Any suggestions how to fix it?

Note: I am forwarding port 8001 on the router the same way I forward port 80, so I guess the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: xampp isn't really suitable for production environments. Is there a reason you are using different ports for each site? Set them to port 80 and use the server name specified and add them into your hosts file found in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc, that is providing you own the domain names that you are using.

Comment: I am actually using it for testing and I need access over internet because of very specific tests. Otherwise, I decided to use different ports because I am not sure how to instruct XAMPP to recognize which site I want to access via port 80.

Comment: use your hosts file and add them in. you will be able to then access them through the specific pc. If you then don't own the domains just modify your hosts file on the external pc to point them domain names to your IP.

Comment: This is my hosts file, how should I change it? `127.0.0.1 site1.com` and 
`127.0.0.1 site2.com`. Also what URL should I type for `site2` in so that the redirect is correct? I now use `my-ip-address:80`?

Comment: use the same one that you type into the httpd-vhosts.conf under ServerName and yes thats fine in your hosts file as that will point to your local pc. You should after restarting apache be able to access via them urls on that pc (if you made any changes in the vhost.. else you shouldn't need to restart)

Comment: I can even now access both websites with the ServerName from httpd-vhosts.conf on the local PC. However, I need to access those websites over internet (from another PC) and noting I have tried works so far.

Comment: forward port 80 to your local pc. If you own the domain name then set your DNS a record to your external ip and then access the site. if not go to another pc and do the same with the hosts file but instead of using 127.0.0.1 use your external ip.

Comment: the domain name is a made up name, so no DNS record. What is left is the second option...I will try it now but still wonder...how will the test PC recognize I want to access `site2` from another PC?

Comment: The pc will take all the DNS values from the hosts file before it makes a DNS query to your ISP's DNS servers. so if you specify your external IP there then it direct you to that pc.

Comment: Ahh understand. Tried as you suggest and it works. Thank you very much for the help! If you post this as an answer I will accept it as such.

Comment: I would but I have a suspicion that this will be marked as off topic soon as it's not a programming question so I would remove the question before you get down voted for it! but not a problem

Comment: Are you sure it's off topic? I have posted multiple XAMPP configuration questions and have even answered a few...and people are quite interested in XAMPP configuration anyway but I guess you know better :)

Comment: Yes, if you look to see whats on topic, this forum is meant for programming related questions. Server fault and super user I would have thought would be more suited to these questions.